# Where clause in With() laravel doesn't work

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Hello I have a little problem with eloquent in Laravel 5.

I have this function:

```
$lists = Model::with(array('relation_with_registered_in_model'=>function($query){
                $query->where("name","cccc");
          }))->get();
```

My poblem is that return always all results, ignoring where clause.

I tried to print my query (generated with function) and if I execute the query in my phpmyadmin it return correct filtered results.

What I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved and Understand my error:

In this posts it is explained https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/problem-with-the-eager-loading-of-laravel-eloquent-orm?page=1

```
// gets only models that have relation matching the closure constraint
// no eager loading of the relation!
Model::whereHas('relation', function ($q) { ...} ); 

// gets ALL models
// and eager loads the relation, but only rows matching the constraint
Model::with(['relation' => function ($q) { ...} ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with single qoute

```
$lists = Model::with(array('relation_with_registered_in_model'=>function($query){
                $query->where('name','cccc');
          }))->get();
```

Comment: thankyou for reply, but no, it doesn't work. anyway Format your code.

Comment: $lists = Model::with(array('relation_with_registered_in_model'=>function($query){ $query->where('name','like','cccc'); }))->get();

Comment: $lists = Model::with(array('relation_with_registered_in_model'=>function($query){ $query->where('name','=','cccc'); }))->get();